# Getting formatting of the initialization string does not confirm to the oledb specification error

Tags: excel, excel-2010, qtp, windows64

I am trying to use excel as a database through QTP and trying to fetch records from it. I am running this code in windows 64 bit system and excel is 2010 version. Below is the code. Please help me what is the issue

```
Dim objCon, objRs
set objCon = createobject("ADODB.Connection")
objCon.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source = O:\Desktop\UFT\Testcases.xlsx;" & "Extended Properties = ""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR = YES;"";" 

Set objRs = createobject("ADODB.Recordset")

objRs.Open "select count(*) from Sheet1 where status = 'Fail'", objcon

msgbox objRs(0)

Set objCon = nothing

Set objRs = nothing
```

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/xlsx-files/  :  in the connection string remove the semicolon after `HDR = YES` : `.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source = O:\Desktop\UFT\Testcases.xlsx;" & "Extended Properties = ""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR = YES"";"`

Comment: Thanks Axel. It's working.